# eTypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Type'

Tags: python, class

I have two programs.
The first one animalGenerator.py:

```
# This program generates a name and an animal type

import Animals

print("Welcome to the animal generator!")
print("This program creates Animal objects")


def main():

    animals = make_list()

    print("\nAnimal List")
    print("-------------")

    display_list(animals)

def make_list():

    animal_list = []

    again = 'y'

    while again.lower() == 'y':

        typ = input("\nWhat type of animal would you like to create? ")

        nam = input("What is the animal's name? ")

        ani = Animals.Animal(typ, nam)

        animal_list.append(ani)

        again = input("\nWould you like to add more animals (y/n)? ")

    return animal_list

def display_list(animal_list):
    for item in animal_list:
        print("\n" + item.get_name() + "the" + item.get_Type() + "is" + item.get_mood())

main()
```

Second program Animals.py:

```
import random

class Animal:

def __init__(self, name, mood, Type):

    self.__name = name
    self.__mood = mood
    self.__animal_type = Type

def set_name(self, name):

    self.__name = name

def set_mood(self, mood):

    self.__mood = mood

def set_animal_type(self, Type):

    self.__animal_type = Type

def toss(self):

    if random.randint(1, 2, 3) == 1:
        self.__mood = 'Happy'
    elif random.randint(1, 2, 3) == 2:
        self.__mood = 'Hungry'
    elif random.randint(1, 2, 3) == 3:
        self.__mood = 'Sleepy'

def get_name(self):

    return self.__name

def get_mood(self):

    return self.__mood

def get_animal_type(self):

    return self.__animal_type
```

I receive an error(title) when I run the first program
This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dahlia\Desktop\McCuneShannonAnimals\animalGenerator.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Dahlia\Desktop\McCuneShannonAnimals\animalGenerator.py", line 11, in main
    animals = make_list()
  File "C:\Users\Dahlia\Desktop\McCuneShannonAnimals\animalGenerator.py", line 30, in make_list
    ani = Animals.Animal(typ, nam)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Type'
```

Could someone please help me figure out how/why "Type" is a missing positional argument?

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong: you are trying to call the initializer (__init__()) with an insufficient amount of arguments.

Comment: The problem lies in `ani = Animals.Animal(typ, nam)` where only two parameters are given while three expected.

Answer (score 1):

You defined `Animals`'s `__init__()` as `def __init__(self, name, mood, Type)`. However, you call it with `ani = Animals.Animal(typ, nam)` - that's two arguments out of the expected three. Ensure that each method is defined properly and that methods are always called properly, according to their definition.

Answer (score -1):

The second program does not look like valid python, there is a level of indentation missing so I am surprised this actually runs at all.

However, to the original problem - you are instantiating Animal with `(typ, nam)`, however in your constructor it also takes a third parameter - `Type` -  `(name, mood, Type)` - this is the positional argument the interpreter is complaining about.

Comment: `type` is not the same as `Type` .

Comment: No, `Type` is not a keyword in Python. `type()` is a built-in function, though.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You beat me by four seconds. `type` isn't technically a keyword, though, either. You can use it as a variable; it's just bad practice.